While performing wudu, some individuals often experience doubts about whether they recited Bismillah or completed specific steps correctly
Sometimes while doing wudu, feel confused if I said Bismillah or not. What should I do in case of such confusions during wudu? Sometimes the confusions are even about if I missed a step. Should I consider these as waswas?

When experiencing doubts during wudu (ablution), Here is how you can handle such situations:
1. Doubt about Saying “Bismillah”

Saying Bismillah before wudu (ablution ) is recommended (Sunnah) according to most scholars, though some consider it obligatory. The obligatory steps of wudu (ablution) are


O believers! When you rise up for prayer, wash your faces and your hands up to the elbows, wipe your heads, and wash your feet to the ankles.
https://quran.com/en/al-maidah/6
Note : Intention and Order of Steps also may matter


If you doubt whether you said Bismillah, you can say it where you are in the wudu process without restarting. The key principle is that


Allah does not burden a soul beyond its capacity
(Qur’an 2:286).


…It is not Allah’s Will to burden you…
https://quran.com/en/al-maidah/6

2. Doubt about Missing a Step in Wudu

If the doubt occurs before completing the wudu, return to the step you are unsure about and complete it properly. For instance, if you’re uncertain about washing your face, wash it again.
If the doubt arises after completing the wudu, ignore the doubt and consider your wudu valid unless you are certain that a step was missed.

3. Considering Waswas (Whispers of  Shaytan)

If these doubts are frequent and lead to overthinking, they are likely waswas. Shaytan uses such doubts to create unnecessary hardship and distractions in worship.

To overcome waswas:

Ignore minor doubts. Trust that you performed the actions unless you are absolutely certain otherwise.
Make dua for protection from Shaytan, such as reciting


أعوذ بالله من الشيطان الرجيم
(I seek refuge in Allah from the accursed Shaytan).
3. Remember that Islam emphasizes ease and not difficulty


…Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship. …
(Qur’an 2:185).

4. General Guidance

Practice mindfulness during wudu (ablution) to help reduce confusion. Perform the steps deliberately and with focus.

Recognize that excessive doubts can lead to unnecessary hardships.


If doubts persist often, treat them as waswas and ignore them. If they are occasional and significant, address them calmly and return to the step in question only if you are certain it was missed.

Ablution (wudhu) is obligatory to perform in its proper sequence, and this sequence does not change due to mere doubt. Instead, the person acts based on what they are most certain of. If one is unsure about completing a specific step, there is no evidence requiring the forgetful person to repeat the ablution or any of its steps unless there is certainty or strong evidence that an obligatory part was missed. The evidence of certainty is the hadith of Abdullah Ibm Zayd (may Allah be pleased with him) said: A man complained to the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) that he felt something while praying -- should he stop his prayer? He said: “No, not unless you hear a sound or notice a smell.” (Al-Bukhari, 2056)
Breaking the prescribed sequence during wudhu—for example, washing the feet and then returning to the face—invalidates the ablution. The same ruling applies to the intention (niyyah), which is essential for wudhu to be valid. However, there may be differing opinions within tarteeb(Order of ablution)
If one forgets to say "Bismillah" at the beginning, there is a difference of opinion among scholars. However, the person may continue with the wudhu and say "Bismillah" upon remembering. There is no need to repeat the ablution. The evidence for this is the hadith:

Allah'messenger(Peace and blessings be upon him) said "There is no ablution for the one who does not mention Allah’s name."
Tirmidhi 25

While some scholars consider this an obligatory command, others view it as recommended.
The obligation of sequence in wudhu is derived from the verse:

"O believers! When you rise for prayer, wash your faces and your hands up to the elbows, wipe your heads, and wash your feet to the ankles." (Surah Al-Ma’idah 5:6)

The Sunnah specifies and clarifies this verse by demonstrating the proper sequence, making it clear that wudhu must be performed in order. Doubt does not override this obligation.
